# What is the scientific name of this plant?

Tags: botany, species-identification, taxonomy

I found this one on a hill here in Palestine. It's about 20 cm in height. Note that it does exist in this regions, but scantily. [image]

Answer (score 14):

The plant is of Lamiaceae family and its common name is Shell Flower or Bells of Ireland.

Its "scientific" aka latin name is [*Moluccella laevis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moluccella_laevis).

[image]